# Is it possible to install OS X Mavericks on 2016 MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I really like the Aqua UI which is available on Mac OS releases before OS X Yosemite 10.10.

It is possible to install OS X Mavericks on my 2016 MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 3):

No. The oldest OS a Mac computer can support is the one the model originally shipped with (for you, 10.12 Sierra). You should be able to get the Mavericks background image from somewhere if that’s what you like about 10.10.

Comment: How about on virtual machine?

Comment: Unfortunately, that won’t work either